Python script using Power BI API works on certain Wi-Fi networks but fails on home Wi-Fi
I have a Python script that utilizes the Power BI API. The script runs without any errors when I'm connected to my mobile hotspot or other Wi-Fi networks. However, when I'm connected to my home Wi-Fi network, I encounter the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:174, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    173 try:
--> 174     conn = connection.create_connection(
    175         (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    176     )
    178 except SocketTimeout:

File c:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py:95, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     94 if err is not None:
---> 95     raise err
     97 raise socket.error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

File c:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py:85, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     84     sock.bind(source_address)
---> 85 sock.connect(sa)
     86 return sock

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:703, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
...
--> 519     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    521 except ClosedPoolError as e:
    522     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.powerbi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.0/myorg/groups/53dd637e-fca5-4e38-9015-3eacb7e57fad/dataflows (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017937610B20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))


I've contacted my internet service provider's support, and they confirmed that there are no restrictions or issues with my home Wi-Fi network. I'm unsure what could be causing this discrepancy in behavior. Any insights or suggestions on troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
I have already contacted my internet service provider's support and attempted to reset both the modem and router to factory defaults, but unfortunately, these steps did not resolve the issue. At this point, I am trying to understand the underlying cause of this problem in order to devise potential solutions. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy would be immensely helpful as I continue troubleshooting.

On your home wifi, are you able to visit https://api.powerbi.com in a regular browser?

Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I'm unable to visit https://api.powerbi.com even on other networks. It consistently returns a 404 error. However, when I ping the host, it communicates properly. Additionally, I executed the command 'Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName api.powerbi.com -InformationLevel Detailed' in PowerShell, and everything seems to be working fine. Despite these checks, the error persists when running the script.
